# pytorch lightning "got an unexpected keyword argument 'weights_summary'"

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch-lightning, optuna

I have been dealing an error when trying to learn Google "temporal fusion transformer" algorithm in anaconda spyder 5.1.5.
Guys, it is very important for me to solve this error. Somebody should say something. I will be very glad.
The example which i use in the link below;

https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/stallion.html

In example, when i come to run the code which i mention below, i got the error

```
study = optimize_hyperparameters(
    train_dataloader,
    val_dataloader,
    model_path="optuna_test",
    n_trials=200,
    max_epochs=50,
    gradient_clip_val_range=(0.01, 1.0),
    hidden_size_range=(8, 128),
    hidden_continuous_size_range=(8, 128),
    attention_head_size_range=(1, 4),
    learning_rate_range=(0.001, 0.1),
    dropout_range=(0.1, 0.3),
    trainer_kwargs=dict(limit_train_batches=30),
    reduce_on_plateau_patience=4,
    use_learning_rate_finder=False  # use Optuna to find ideal learning rate or use in-built learning rate finder
)
```

Here is the error below

```
A new study created in memory with name: no-name-fe7e21ce-3034-4679-b60a-ee4d5c9a4db5
[W 2022-10-21 19:36:49,382] Trial 0 failed because of the following error: TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weights_summary'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\omer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\optuna\study\_optimize.py", line 196, in _run_trial
    value_or_values = func(trial)
  File "C:\Users\omer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytorch_forecasting\models\temporal_fusion_transformer\tuning.py", line 150, in objective
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
  File "C:\Users\omer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\argparse.py", line 345, in insert_env_defaults
    return fn(self, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weights_summary'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [3] in <cell line: 1>
    study = optimize_hyperparameters(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytorch_forecasting\models\temporal_fusion_transformer\tuning.py:217 in optimize_hyperparameters
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=n_trials, timeout=timeout)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\optuna\study\study.py:419 in optimize
    _optimize(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\optuna\study\_optimize.py:66 in _optimize
    _optimize_sequential(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\optuna\study\_optimize.py:160 in _optimize_sequential
    frozen_trial = _run_trial(study, func, catch)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\optuna\study\_optimize.py:234 in _run_trial
    raise func_err

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\optuna\study\_optimize.py:196 in _run_trial
    value_or_values = func(trial)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytorch_forecasting\models\temporal_fusion_transformer\tuning.py:150 in objective
    trainer = pl.Trainer(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\argparse.py:345 in insert_env_defaults
    return fn(self, **kwargs)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weights_summary'
```

What is problem with the code? Is there anyone to help me, please?

Comment: Why nobody tell anyhing?

Comment: No idea. Just ran in to the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

the `weights_summary` argument was removed starting from Pytorch-Lightning version 1.7.0. [See pull request here](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/pull/13070). As an alternative, use parameter `enable_model_summary`, as [described in the docs here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/trainer.html).

Answer (score 0):

So, i had same ploblom as you have.

I suggest you find out "weights_suammry" variable on your code

I use .yaml file and put parameters of pytorch_lightning.Trainer automatically using hydra also use strategy=DDPStrategy(find~)

i just realize there was weights_summary in .yaml file,

the structure was

```
trainer:
 _target_: ~~
 ~~:
 weights_summary : "top"
```

and i remove weights_summary on it and the plobloms have solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed pytorch-forecasting from conda-forge. The current version is v0.10.2 for conda-forge while it is v0.10.3 for pip. See https://github.com/jdb78/pytorch-forecasting. They solved this issue in v0.10.3. So you can either reinstall it with pip or downgrade pytorch-lightning, like

```
conda remove pytorch-lightning
conda install pytorch-lightning=1.6.4 -c conda-forge
conda remove pytorch-forecasting
conda install pytorch-forecasting -c conda-forge
```

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary measure, there is a way to directly modify the installed library file.

In my case, line 147 of file `/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_forecasting/models/temporal_fusion_transformer/tuning.py`

```
weights_summary=[None, "top"][optuna_verbose < optuna.logging.INFO] ,
```

was modified as follows.

```
enable_model_summary=[None, "top"][optuna_verbose < optuna.logging.INFO],
```

Answer (score -1):

So it seems like there is an incompatibility issue with the pytorch_lightning version that you are using. Your version is probably to advanced.

I'm using pytorch_ligtning v1.5, and pytorch_forecasting at 0.10.2, and it works.